# PHP Displaying an image small issue

Tags: php, image

Kind of a simple question. Is there a way to make `<img src>` display a picture if you do not specify the image format?

For example, instead of writing:
`<img src="imagename1.png" width="200px" height="250px"/>`

I'd write

```
<img src="imagename1" width="200px" height="250px"/>
```

and it would simply show any image named imagename1 regardless what the file extension name is.

I did actually write it like in the example and my test website on my WAMPserver works fine and doesn't care what the file extension is, it just looks for the name. But my live version does not show images unless I add the .png or other needed extension to the `<img src>`. Any ideas what might be wrong? Might there be a better way to display pictures? Any help is invaluable, thank you for your time!

Edit #1

If I remove password protection for the directory, the `.htaccess` file goes back to it's default state. What it contains:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit 
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language. 
<IfModule mime_module>   
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml 
</IfModule> 
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Removing password protection doesn't help the issue though...

Comment: Did you amend the `.htaccess` file on your test server

Comment: Not directly, no. But currently my site is password protected, due to me still setting/changing stuff. You reckon it might be causing the problems? I'll go check that out.

Comment: If I remove password protection for the directory, the ```.thaccess``` file goes back to it's default state. What it contains: ```# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit```

Comment: Removing password protection doesn't help the issue though...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post relevant info/data there, not in the comments

Comment: Sorry, will do, thank you!

Comment: Your server where it works, probably has [`MultiViews`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling `MultiViews` on the server resolves the issue.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews